# What data is sent to PayPal cancel_return

Tags: paypal

Auto Return is on, PDT is on. I also use IPN but, so far as I can tell, IPN is not activated by a cancelled payment. The closest answer I've seen to my question is "there won't be much useful information in there, except a flag that says payment was canceled." But exactly what data is sent?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am much mistaken, nothing except `item_name`. I've tried sending application-specific data by appending it to the `cancel_return` URL as parameters, in the button form, but according to my notes it didn't work.